# Can I buy a TLD?

Tags: dns, domain-name

It's a simple question about TLD(Top-Level-Domain). 
Can someone purchase a Top level domain and act as a domain root? 
if so, then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but its going to cost you... $185,000 to be exact. The current intake for this year is over however check again next year on the [ICANN](https://gtldreg.icann.org) website for details. Have a peek at some [news articles](http://www.techspot.com/news/47031-icann-selling-custom-top-level-domains-for-185000.html) for more details

Comment: 2015 update: They're **still** working through the backlog from the 2012 application period. It could easily be another three to five years before they're done, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: And they are still working through the backlog ... and it all seems to be a total epic facepalm failure